# SQLite: determining whether any portion of a string contains any one (of multiple) strings returned by a select query

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, full-text-search, sql-like

I'm having trouble figuring out how to ask SQLite to return all entries in a table where "column" contains text found in the results of a select statement.

I would like it to work a little like this, if this makes any sense:

```
select * from table1`
where ("%" || (column) || "%") like in
("%" || (select different_column from table2) || "%")`
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Please let me know if anyone needs more information.

EDIT: My apologies, I have edited the formatting to be more readable and have added more specifics below.  I have also deleted my ridiculously unreadable comments in favor of just editing this question.

table1 (alerts) contains a column called "lookup_info", which stores a string. The string generally looks like this:

```
--- 
:account_description: Administrator 
:alertable_class: Computer 
:alertable_name: exampledotnet 
:network_account_type: 
:wmi:
:user: exampledomain\administrator
```

table2 (devices) contains a column called "name", which stores a string.  The string generally looks like this:

```
so-ws-rm101
```

What I would like to do is return all entries in table1 (alerts) where table1's "lookup_info" column does **not** contain somewhere within it a computer name stored in table2 (devices) under table2's "name" column.

Basically, there are some alerts that reference computer names that no longer exist.  I want those alerts.

Thank you.

EDIT: I have created an fts3 table by the name of alerts_fts that contains the lookup_info column of all entries within the alerts table.  I'm trying my search again using full text search this time.  This is the query I am using:

```
select *
  from alerts_fts 
  where alerts_fts.lookup_info match ( select group_concat(name, " OR ") 
                         from Devices
                         group by "x")
```

This should make the query look like:

```
select *
  from alerts_fts 
  where alerts_fts.lookup_info match (cw-ws-example OR so-p2-132-example OR 
                         ... OR so-p4-lastexample)
                         group by "x")
```

Naturally, this is still not working.  The query returns nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please modify your question to include sample data and sample results.

Comment: Thank you for your time @GordonLinoff.  I have edited my question in an attempt to increase its clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do this with a join:

```
select t1.**
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.column like '%'||t2.column||'%'
```

If there is the possibility of more than one match, you'll want to add `distinct`:

```
select distinct t1.*
. . .
```

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
select t1.**
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.column like '%'||t2.columnA||'%' or
        t1.column like '%'||t2.columnB||'%' or 
        t1.column like '%'||t2.columnC||'%' or 
        . . .
```

Based on your edits, I think you want a left outer join and then a check for no match:

```
select table1.*
from table1 left outer join
     table2
     on t1.column like '%'||t2.column||'%'
where t2.column is null
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't seem to work.  Thank you for your persistence.  This issue is starting to bother me.

Comment: I edited my question again, just added a line beginning with "basically," thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi again Gordon and @sgeddes.  Once again I have edited my post to include what approach I am working on now.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Like with In, but you could do something like this assuming you want to match either column back:

```
Select Distinct table1.* 
From table1 
  Join table2 On 
    column1 like '%'||different_column||'%' 
    Or different_column like '%'||column1||'%'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9aa5d/2)

Comment: Thank you @sgeddes for your reply.  Unfortunately that does not return the desired information.  I have edited my question and added more information.